# Почему бедренная часть называется "крестец"?

Tags: этимология

Район поясницы называют еще крестец. Но, честно говоря, зная анатомию, я не могу предположить, что там может иметь крестообразную форму, что бы дало название этой части туловища.
Почему его так называют, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Крестец часть позвоночника, не туловища. Ушковидные с тыльной стороны формы, именуемые крыльями на уровне пятого (верхнего) позвонка, вместе с вертикальной осью сочленения образуют крест.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечная (нижняя) часть позвоночного столба, состоящая из пяти сросшихся позвонков, примыкающих к костям таза.  Название крестца связано с тем, что он своими пятью сросшимися позвонками похож на маленький крест.
(По данным Малого академического словаря и этимологического словаря Шанского)

Answer (score -1):

Крестец по-латыи os sacrum. Это же слово переводится как "священный". А поскольку большинство верующих в мире христиане, слово "священный" ассоциируется с крестом. Думаю, отсюда и "крестец". С другой стороны, крестец - место пересечения позвоночника и таза, нечто длинное и продольное пересекается с поперечным и более коротким. Возможно, кому-то это и напомнило небольшой крест, крестец.

Comment: Os sacrum — это два слова, первое из которых "кость". А вообще, вопрос был по этимологии, а не по вольным ассоциациям. Вторая часть Вашего ответа уже была озвучена ранее (со ссылками на авторитетные источники).

Comment: @grizzly, по сути согласен, но по форме... У меня особое отношение к "озвучиванию", но тут любой скажет, что наш сайт был и остается "немым", неозвученным.

Comment: @М_Г В словарях (см., например, словарь Ефремовой) есть значение "озвучить — довести до общего сведения". Хоть оно и помечено как разговорное, но мне нравится. Это значение появилось не так давно и я уверен, что оно закрепится в языке.

Comment: @grizzly Не могу поверить, что это применительно к доведению до общего сведения в письменной форме. Кстати, здесь в словаре Ефремовой такого нет: https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/319227.html

Comment: @М_Г По Вашей ссылке оно в каком-то другом месте: https://slovar.cc/rus/tolk/67183.html, странно. В Викисловаре тоже есть. Ваше право не верить :) А мне нравится это значение.

Comment: @grizzly По Вашей ссылке: "Доводить до всеобщего сведения, предавать гласности, **зачитывать** что-либо". Зачитывать, а не записывать.

Comment: @М_Г Да, значение *зачитывать* **тоже** есть. Мы по-разному пользуемся словарями? Я не хочу спорить. Если посмотрите значения в [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), Вы поймёте меня лучше. Я часто слышу это слово в подобном значении. Ещё часто пишут: "я говорил об этом ранее" вместо "я писал об этом ранее". Это пример из той же серии, и в словарях об этом сказано явно (см. Кузнецова).

Comment: @grizzly, Да, похоже, Вы не одиноки. Слово с корнем *звук*  стало немым. Надеюсь, ненадолго.